# QWebEngineView not closing properly in some cases

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I found that `QWebEngineView` behaves very strange (Windows PyQt5 with Qt 5.7.0) and in some cases does not finish properly leaving the application hanging. The following snippet works fine. But if you uncomment both lines marked with `#1` and `#2` and then try to close the application, the application get hung. The same happens if you uncomment only `#3`. I tried this with other widgets than `QWebEngineView`, and no problems occurred.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
widget = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
# widget.load(QtCore.QUrl("http:/www.google.com"))  #1
mainWindow.setCentralWidget(widget)
# mainWindow.setCentralWidget(None)                 #2
# widget.deleteLater()                              #3
mainWindow.show()
result = app.exec_()
sys.exit(result)
```

This is the shortest code which can reproduce the error. But what I need in my much larger application is to set web engine view as the central widget and then with menu actions close it and set another widget as central widget. Any ideas how to fix the behaviour and achieve the expected behaviour? Or am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE:

I found even simpler example exhibiting the described issue. Running this on Windows, PyQt 5.7 leaves the application hanging.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
widget.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

UPDATE2:
I create a ticket for this as this seems to me as a bug. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57228 However before the fix is delivered, any workaround would be very appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce this on Linux. In your actual application, I suppose you could just `hide()` the web-view instead of deleting it.

Comment: Did you try this in PyQt5? Or similar code in Qt5 (C++)? My wild guess is that there are some Python references not handled correctly when deleting the widget which results GC not disposing the widget. Therefore I think this will be no problem in C++.

Comment: Unfortunately just hiding the widget is not a solution in my case. :( Note: I also tries the older WebKit (predecessor of WebEngine) and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I used Qt-5.7 and PyQt-5.7, and neither of your examples causes a problem on Linux. It's highly unlikely this is a Qt bug, so you're probably wasting your time reporting it on their tracker. How are you running the script? If it was gc issue, you'd normally get a crash, rather than a hang. And how did you install Qt/PyQt?

Comment: I used the latest WinPython distribution.

Comment: That's very likely the source of the problem. To test things properly, you need to use a vanilla install (`pip3 install PyQt5`) and run the script in a command window.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I used the very latest version of Python 3.5.3.2 and clean installed the latest PyQt5. I am afraid the issue is still there on Windows. The process is still alive when I close the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that I need to add `del widget` and `del app` just between `result = app.exec_()` and `sys.exit(result)`. Then it works just as expected. Probably not an issue in `QtWebEngine` but in `PyQt5` not properly releasing all references.

See comments for https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57228